# stacks Assignment how to match bracket left and right

Tags: stack

its been a week im trying to figure out how to finish this assignment. Its kind of not clear how to connect my if statements with stacks.

here is my codes, its made of 3 files

the assignment problem is, brackets and parenthesis should match, which means if we have left bracket, after that should be right one, otherwise it will say not valid.

i'll be very happy any hint or fixes.

### cstack.h file

```
#include <iostream>

class FullStack{};

class EmptyStack{};


class cstack

{

private:
    int top;        // Index to top of the stack
    char data[21];      // The stack

public:
    cstack();       // Class constructor
    void Push(char);    // Push an item onto the stack
    void Pop();     // Pop an item from the stack
    bool Top();
    bool IsEmpty();     // Return true if stack is empty
    bool IsFull();      // Return true if stack is full


};
```

### cstack.cpp file

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include "cstack.h"
   #include <stack>
   #include <cstring>
   using namespace std;



   cstack::cstack()
   {
top = -1;
   }

   bool cstack::IsEmpty()
   {
return (top == -1);
   }

   bool cstack::IsFull()
   {
return (top == 21);
   }

   void cstack::Push(char newItem)
   {
if (IsFull())
{
    throw FullStack();

}
top++;
data[top] = newItem;
    }


    void cstack::Pop()
    {
if(IsEmpty())
{
    throw EmptyStack();
}
top--;
    }


    bool cstack::Top()
    {
if (IsEmpty())
{
    throw EmptyStack();
}   

return data[top];

    }
```

### test.cpp file

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <iomanip>
   #include <cstring>
   using namespace std;
   #include "cstack.h"

   bool isValidExpression (cstack&, char*);

   int main (void)
   {    
char expression[21];
cstack stack1;

cout<< "Enter an expression: ";
cin >>expression;

if (isValidExpression (stack1, expression))
{
    cout << "\nIt's a valid expression\n\n";
}
else
{
    cout << "\nIt's NOT a valid expression\n\n";
}
system("pause");    
return 0;
}

bool isValidExpression (cstack& stackA, char* strExp)
 {


for(int i = 0; i < 21 ; i++)
{   


     if( strExp[stackA.Top()] == '[' || strExp[stackA.Top()] == '{' ||                       strExp[stackA.Top()] == '(')
    {
        stackA.Push( strExp[i] );

    }



        if( strExp[stackA.Top()] == ']' || strExp[stackA.Top()] == '}' || strExp[stackA.Top()] == ')')
    {



        if(strExp[i] == '[' && strExp[stackA.Top()] == ']')
        {
            return true;

        }else 

        {
        return false;


    }

}
}
return true;
    }
```

Comment: Semantically, `Pop()` should return the element that has been popped.

Comment: Also, I believe you've not pasted the correct test.cpp, its the same as cstack.cpp.

Comment: My bad, i just corrected, and btw, as far as i know, on this Assignemnt i dont need to use pop(), they told me we have to push() only.

Comment: @Nikhil - that's not always a requirement (see e.g. the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) definition). Since you can always use `Top` before `Pop` anyway, there's no real requirement for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this problem you normaly do this:

- take each char from the input
- push every opening bracket on the stack
- if you get a closing bracket check top element of your stack.

  - if that element is the right opening bracket remove it from stack.
  - if that element is not the right opening bracket return false.

As Nikhil mentioned in the comment, normaly `pop()` should return the popped element, but in following code I used your stack.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 21 ; i++)
{   


 if(strExp[i] == '[' || strExp[i] == '{' || strExp[i] == '(')
{
    stackA.Push( strExp[i] );

}



    if( strExp[i] == ']')
    {
       if(!stackA.IsEmpty && stackA.Top() == '[')
       {
         stackA.Pop();
       } else {
                return false;
       }
    }

    if( strExp[i] == '}')
    {
       if(!stackA.IsEmpty && stackA.Top() == '{')
       {
         stackA.Pop();
       } else {
                return false;
       }
    }

    if( strExp[i] == ')')
    {
       if(!stackA.IsEmpty && stackA.Top() == '(')
       {
         stackA.Pop();
       } else {
                return false;
       }
    }

}

return true;
```

edit: 
when using ´pop()´ whenever we find a matching closing bracket we make sure, that on top of the stack there is always the last opened bracket. You can close that bracket or open another one, but you can't close earlier brackets.

The error you described occurs when you find a closing bracket and have an empty stack. So you have to check that first. `if(!stackA.IsEmpty && stackA.Top == '[')`. See my edited code. Normaly with this code "[]" should be valid, i'll doublecheck and tell you, if i find another mistake.

Comment: Thank you so much @Kayz, but i have know why are we using pop() here, also i tried to run this. 
<br>

input is:  []
output is:   It's NOT a valid expression


and is i input ][
output is error on the cstack.cpp\top()\return data[top]; has a problem

Comment: why is the return typ of `Top()` bool? Shouldn't it be int?

Comment: i changed the bool Top() to int Top(), i also added your  **if(!stackA.IsEmpty && stackA.Top == '[')**. it marked with red underline by saying that    <<Error: a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function>>,    again thank you @Kayz youre a life saver :)

Comment: Sorry, it seems like I forgor the brackets. Should be `!stackA.IsEmpty()`

Comment: thank you soooo much @kayz, code is running, there is a bug, but its ok, at least i can submit it :)